# Convert index data from raw indexes to date-index format

Tags: kdb

I am able to get index data for certain data in a partition in the following 2 formats.

1. Where first each is the partition, and last each is the index in that partition

```
form1:((2023.07.31;2);(2023.07.31;3);(2023.07.31;9);(2023.08.01;4);(2023.08.01;32);(2023.08.03;5))
```

2. The index is offset by the date. The offset value is the count of the partition stored in a dictionary. However, the first key is first[partition]-1 and its set as 0 since there is no index offset. And there is no offset for the final partition as we will not need that information.

```
form2:(2 3 9 24 52 75)
ioffset:(2023.07.30 2023.07.31 2023.08.01 )!(0;20;50)
```

(I could also make the ioffset an aggregate, so its `(0 20 70)` instead.

ex 1:for item 24 - it is more than 20 but less than 50, so its in partition 2023.08.01 and needs to use the offset for 2023.07.31. So 24-20=4, so its at index 4 in the partition.

ex2: for item 75, it is above 50+20 so its one partition above 2023.08.01 which is 2023.08.02. 75-50-20=5 so its at index 5.

I want to convert either form1 or form2 into the following format:

```
finalForm:(2023.07.31 2023.08.01 2023.08.02)!((2 3 9);(4 32);(enlist 5))
```

I can use both form1 or form2, whichever is fastest to convert formats as I can get data for form1 & form2 in about the same amount of time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can use [`group`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/group/) to do this

```
q)form1[;1] group form1[;0]
2023.07.31| 2 3 9
2023.08.01| 4 32
2023.08.03| ,5
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form2 doesn't contain information to map the values to the dates? It's not possible to do it without that information. If I did have it you could do:

```
q)form2:(2023.07.30 2023.07.31 2023.08.01)!(2 3 9;24 52;75)
q)ioffset:(2023.07.30 2023.07.31 2023.08.01 )!(0;20;50)
q)form2-sums ioffset
2023.07.30| 2 3 9
2023.07.31| 4 32
2023.08.01| 5
```

Comment: I specifically don't have dates for form2.
I believe I do have all the required information as the indexes are already offset by the count of the previous partition.

So in the example of 24, I know it is in 2023.08.01 because it is above the aggregate  count of 2023.07.31 which is 0+20. So we just do 24-20, hence it is at index 4 of the 2023.08.01 partition. 

If I had an index of 100, in this case it would be in 2023.08.02 partition because the aggregate sum of ioffset is 70, which is smaller than 100. Hence it is at index 30 on 2023.08.02.